# Is there a way to quickly open symbol manager for current file in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been coding in Xcode for a while, the symbol manager (I named it) for current file is useful, but I can not find a shortcut for it.

Is there any way to quickly open it, through the keyboard.

Comment: sorry for I am not able to post an image because of my low reputation

Comment: Are you means of `Reveal in Symbol Navigator`?

Comment: The area on top of each editor, you can click to reveal symbols for current file, while "Reveal in Symbol Navigator" show symbols for current project

Comment: Is this it? http://imgur.com/zYcicZP

Answer (score 4):

It's `Show Document Items`. You can change its default shortcut(`^6`) to your custom shortcut in the `Key Bindings` panel of the `Preferences`:

[image]